# Rails model method rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have the following test:

it 'should return array of other cars at garage (excluding itself)' do
    g1 = FactoryGirl.create(:garage)

```
c1 = FactoryGirl.create(:car)
c1.garage = g1

c2 = FactoryGirl.create(:car)
c2.name = "Ford 1"
c2.garage = g1

c3 = FactoryGirl.create(:car)
c3.name = "VW 1"
c3.garage = g1

expect(c1.other_cars_at_garage).to eq([c2, c3])
```

end

which should test this method on my model:

```
  def other_cars_at_garage
    garage.cars.where.not(id: self.id)
  end
```

When I run the test, it fails as it returns: `#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>`

How should I get this test to pass?  How do I check for an AR::AssociationRelation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving the association between c1/c2/c3 and g1

```
c1 = FactoryGirl.create(:car)
c1.garage = g1
c1.save #this saves g1 in c1's garage

c2 = FactoryGirl.create(:car)
c2.name = "Ford 1"
c2.garage = g1
c2.save

c3 = FactoryGirl.create(:car)
c3.name = "VW 1"
c3.garage = g1
c3.save
```

In addition, it's probably best to use

```
expect(c1.other_cars_at_garage).to match_array([c2, c3])
```

Notice the `match_array` instead of `eq`, this means the order of the array is unimportant, where as eq means the order of the array is important